# Placement of JQuery Scripts with multiple other scripts?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, typeahead, bootstrap-tokenfield

I wrote this script

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/my/GetTagsByID",
     data: {
         Link_ID: LId
     },
     datatype: "json",
     success: function(result) {
         $('#tokenfield-typeahead').val('Success 1, Success 2')
     },
     error: function(jqXHR) {
         alert(jqXHR.status);
     }
 })
```

The issue is but I don't know what should be the exact location of `SCRIPTS`

When I up it in this way:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/dist/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/dist/css/tokenfield-typeahead.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/dist/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The results are the following 
[image]

This means, I can use `TokenField` and `TypeAhead` but it is not replacing values `$('#tokenfield-typeahead').val('Success 1, Success 2')` which means I cannot access jQuery?

But when I switch location for `Jquery` script to this (moving JQUERY to the bottom):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/dist/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/dist/css/tokenfield-typeahead.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/dist/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

I get the following results 
[image]

I cannot use `Tokenfield`, I cannot use `TypeAhead` anymore.

What am I supposed to do?

**Added new  code**
I have added the new code, it seems like JQuery is unable to recognise tokenfiled as a function - How can I resolve this where i have added all required references - See the code below (i am getting same error in console and no matter where I test) - Please run the Code and click the button

```js
$('#bt').click(function() {

  $('#tokenfield-typeahead').tokenfield('setTokens', ['blue', 'red', 'white']);

});
```

```html
<link href="http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/dist/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>



<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield-typeahead" value="Temp 1, Temp 2" data-limit="10" placeholder="Enter tags" />

<button id="bt">Click me</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - Thanks for T.J to advising run the script in console

The issue was, Bootstrap.min.js needed to be loaded `before` Tokenfiled (JS) - Doing that fixed the issue and now JQuery can identify Tokenfield as a function and works as intended. I still don't under why Bootstrap was not loading because I had it in my _Layout page and in the Bundle. In any case i will see how can i re-arrange my script bundles -

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> ...which means I cannot access jQuery?

No, it doesn't mean that at all. It just means that `val` isn't doing what you expect.

That doesn't surprise me. It's **extremely** likely that the tokenfield plugin you're using needs you to use a tokenfield-specific method to set the values, not `val`. Glancing at [the documentation](https://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/), it seems to be `tokenfield('setTokens', ...)`:

```
$('#tokenfield-typeahead').tokenfield('setTokens', 'Success 1,Success2');
```

> What am I supposed to do?

Put jQuery before any plugins, since the plugins need jQuery to be there in order to hook themselves up; always refer to documentation as your first action when things don't work as expected; and use the correct method for setting the "value" in the tokenfield.

Comment: I have looked again very deeply and trying to do this `$('#tokenfield-typeahead').tokenfield('setTokens', ['blue', 'red', 'white']);` but still no Luck

Comment: @aliusman: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), being sure to link all libs from the provided list or a CDN (like https://cdnjs.com/).

Comment: I get the following error :( "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",

Comment: @aliusman: That's because you have a missing `)` after your argument list. Seriously, it's a basic syntax error, you should be able to resolve it yourself.

Comment: sorry, yes, but i get an error, it says `$(...).tokenfield is not a function`

Comment: @aliusman: Open the web console and deal with the error there.

Comment: ok but why i have lost so much REP for this question? I thought my question was well written with code and screenshots

Comment: Please see my code above, if you run and click the button, I get the same error here I get in my local browser console

Comment: @aliusman: Again: Open the web browser console (Ctrl+Shift+I, or F12, or on a Mac Cmd+Shift+I), and deal with the errors there. It's the same error as the last time I posted this comment, just on different resources.

Comment: T.J ok thank you, what I am trying to understand why the error is showing up in stakoverflow's code snippet, it looks like it is universal and I all the solutions I get is to add jQuery.ui but that doesn't resolve the issue, any idea what is causing the issue, sorry to be annoying